# Doctrine orm yml mapping ontToOne ReflectionException

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, yaml, one-to-one

I got a small problem i try to map my entities in a one to one relation.
Im using Doctrine 2.4 and Symfony.
Here are my Entities:

```
Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Foo:
  type: entity
  oneToOne:
    bar:
      targetEntity: Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Bar
      joinColumn:
        name: bar_id
        referencedColumnName: id

  table: foo_params
  fields:
    id:
      id: true
      type: integer
      column: id
      generator:
        strategy: IDENTITY
    fooName:
      type: string
      length: 80
      nullable: false
      column: foo_name
      options:
        comment: name of the placeholder for this parameter
    fooType:
      nullable: false
      column: foo_type

Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Bar:
  type: entity
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      column: id
      generator:
        strategy: IDENTITY
```

The error im getting when i run on Symfony2 as example a migration diff is:

```
  [ReflectionException]
  Property Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Foo::$bar does not exist
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Show us your `Foo` :)

Comment: added now the whole foo.orm.yml ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `.php` class file ;)

Comment: I am currently not useing the `.php` file, i used to have annotations, but i'm switching currently to yml-entities.

The diff which i generate is only between the yml-entities and the database, the `.php` doesn't influence here at this time. The relation of the `bar_id` should be one-to-one or null, and should not be bidirectional.

Comment: Yes, but you must have `.php` file. ;) While you don't have to choose annotations, `.php` file is mandatory here and `YML` is used to describe bindings between `PHP` class members and database column

Comment: You are right, and that solved my issue.
I had the false Entity the whole time. There around 70 Entities which are used.

Comment: Great, glad I could nudge you in right direction ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Acme\DemoBundle
```

and then

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

It won't map anything without it, format is irrelevant.